# Getting Array keys in POST method using POSTMAN in Python 3 Flask-Restful API

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, flask, flask-restful

How to get the value of array in postman using  parser = reqparse.RequestParser() in flask api?

[image]

Im getting an error says: NoneType' object is not subscriptable

And here is my code:

```
class CreateUser(Resource):

    def post(self):
        try: 
          conn = None
          parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
          parser.add_argument('username', type = str)

          args = parser.parse_args()
          name = args['username'][0]

          return name
        except Exception as e:
            x = str(e)
            x.replace('\n', '')
            return {'status' : 'failed', 'message' : str(x)}
        finally:
            if conn is not None:
                conn.close()
```

im getting error with this name = args['username'][0] and i also try to make this too name = args[0]['username'] and still error appears and when i just make this like name = args['username'] the postman replies null. please help me.

Comment: `args` is `None` possibly because there is no `str` for `username`. Have you tried `parser.add_argument('username', type=list, location='json')`? Or `parser.add_argument('username', action='append')`?

Comment: i also try that but still, the error shows above in postman. please help me

Comment: ok you've edited your answer, im going to try type=list, location'json'

Comment: still getting an error, what about revision of code? can you give a code that can get those keys in array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
def post(self):
try: 
  conn = None
  parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
  parser.add_argument('username[0]', type = str)
  parser.add_argument('username[1]', type = str)

  args = parser.parse_args()
  name = args['username[0]']

  return name
except Exception as e:
    x = str(e)
    x.replace('\n', '')
    return {'status' : 'failed', 'message' : str(x)}
finally:
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()
```

Editing for multiple params
form data should be like this

```
username: "user1"
username: "user2"
username: "user3"
```

Yes you can pass multiple values with same key

```
def post(self):
try: 
  conn = None
  parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
  parser.add_argument('username', type = str, action='append')
  args = parser.parse_args()
  name = args['username']
  print(name) # ['user1', 'user2','user3'] you can traverse over this list
```

Comment: What if he doesn't know how many username args he will have coming in for the request?

Comment: oh sir, thanks for this :) one more thing, how can i make it dynamically? can i make it in a loop statement? getting the length of json request and make it like this?

json_dict = request.get_json(force=True, silent=True)

 for i in len(json_dict):

    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()

    parser.add_argument('username[i]', type = str)

    name = args['username[i]']

how can i make it like that? thanks for your help :)

Comment: then you should send json body as request instead of form data  json body can be {"username":["user1","user2", "user3"]} and in your post method read json array and traverse through it

Comment: i dont have any problem with sending it in raw json. I need it in form type because it is the way how to make a format in sending a data through api using a kotlin. can you make it dynamically? what if they send me thousands of it? how can i apply it in a loop statement?

Comment: Edited my answer have a look

Comment: thanks for editing it for me and helping me a lot. but the code you added doesn't print 3 users as i made it the same with mine that i have to input 3 keys same as you did sir. but only 1 key has been printed out.

Comment: Edited again forgot to add action='append' in parser.add_argument